# add-in or tool to generate a DB Schema out of Entity framework edmx files?

Tags: nhibernate, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, fluent-nhibernate

i have been using NHibernate in TDD environment and found it very helpful to be able to generate schema out of mapping file etc... And now i'm thinking of going with Entity Framework for next project. So just wonder if there is any equivalent library or tools for EF to generate DB schema etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Have a look at this [model first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff830362.aspx) document.